# Fail writing dht11 sensor in mysql with nodeMCU

Tags: php, mysql, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm having trouble writing my data collected with the DHT11 sensor using PHP + MYSQL with the nodeMCU (ESP8266MCU).

On the serial monitor says that it is not possible to connect to the server and not execute the get command

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <SimpleDHT.h>

// WiFi - Coloque aqui suas configurações de WI-FI
const char ssid[] = "WIFI-D767480";
const char psw[] = "986557D124D480";

// Site remoto - Coloque aqui os dados do site que vai receber a requisição GET
const char http_site[] = "192.168.23.1";
const int http_port = 80;

// Variáveis globais
WiFiClient client;
IPAddress server(192,168,23,1); //Endereço IP do servidor - http_site
int pinDHT11 = D2;
SimpleDHT11 dht11;

void setup() {
  delay(30000); //Aguarda 30 segundos 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("NodeMCU - writing data in BD via GET");
  Serial.println("Waiting connection");

  // Tenta conexão com Wi-fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, psw);
  while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay(100);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.print("\nWI-FI sucefull connection: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

}

void loop() {

  //Leitura do sensor DHT11
  delay(3000); //delay entre as leituras
  byte temp = 0;
  byte humid = 0;
  if (dht11.read(pinDHT11, &temp, &humid, NULL)) {
    Serial.print("Fail in sensor.");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("writing data in BD: ");
  Serial.print((int)temp); Serial.print(" *C, "); 
  Serial.print((int)humid); Serial.println(" %");

  // Envio dos dados do sensor para o servidor via GET
  if ( !getPage((int)temp,(int)humid) ) {
    Serial.println("GET request failed");
  }
}

// Executa o HTTP GET request no site remoto
bool getPage(int temp, int humid) {
  if ( !client.connect(server, http_port) ) {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect to site ");
    return false;
  }
  String param = "?temp=" + String(temp) + "&humid=" + String(humid); //Parâmetros com as leituras
  Serial.println(param);
  client.println("GET /weather/insert_weather.php" + param + " HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Host: ");
  client.println(http_site);
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println();
  client.println();

    // Informações de retorno do servidor para debug
  while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }
  return true;
}
```

I tried to modify the following line, but without success:

```
client.println("GET /weather/insert_weather.php" + param + " HTTP/1.1");
```

for: client.println("GET /weather/insert_weather.php" + param);
and: client.println("GET /weather/insert_weather.php?+param+\r\n");

the error is in the attached image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0RHn.jpg)
I tried others code too, but withoud sucess.

My php code is:

```
<?php
$temp = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'temp', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$humid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'humid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
if (is_null($temp) || is_null($humid) ) {
  //Gravar log de erros
  die("Dados inválidos");
} 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "maker";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  //Gravar log de erros
  die("Não foi possível estabelecer conexão com o BD: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO weather (wea_temp, wea_humid) VALUES ($temp,$humid)";

if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
  //Gravar log de erros
  die("Erro na gravação dos dados no BD");
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I'm using WAMP v. 3.1.17
tank you!

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I used fictitious addresses, but thanks for the warning

Answer (score 0):

try using a POST request instead of a GET and in your PHP code have it use $_POST[myvariable] to get the contents of the body of the HTTP request. Also, there is an HTTP [library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient) for the ESP8266 that you can get that has functions made to send HTTP requests. Here is a snippet from one of my projects where I did pretty much exactly the same thing that you are trying to do now

```
 if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){   //Check WiFi connection status

  HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient

  postData = "reading=" + readingData + "&data=" + ADCData; //create the string that 
  // will be sent in the POST request

  http.begin("http://192.168.0.179:80/phptesting.php");      //Specify request 
  destination
  //send it to a .php file which can extract data from POST requests.

  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  //Specify 
  //  content-type header

  int httpCode = http.POST(postData);   //Send the request
  String payload = http.getString();                  //Get the response payload

  Serial.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
  Serial.println(payload);    //Print request response payload. If you get anything 
  besides '200' something is up.

  http.end();  //Close connection
```

Try this and if it doesn't work let me know and I can send you the rest of the code from this project.

Comment: Can you send me a complete code this project? I've this problem a long time and don't find the solution =(
Could you send to me the PHP code too?? I would also be grateful

Comment: here's a link to my project. this does almost exactly what you're trying to do right now. let me know if you need more help with it           https://github.com/Skytrobb/Changing-HTML-Elements-With-Arduino?files=1